# Access 2016 - Forms disappeared when opening a .mdb (created in Access 2003) in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2016

I have opened a .mdb file which was initially created in Microsoft Access 2003, within Access 2016. 
I can see all the tables and macros, but all the forms seem to have disappeared.

Why? I have added the file as a Trusted Location and Enabled All Content.

Comment: Create a new (empty) database in accdb format, and import all objects from the old mdb file.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll give that a go. Many thanks

Comment: I tried this but even when I open the old mdb in access 2016 I cannot see the forms to import into the new .accdb.

Comment: Then the forms somehow are broken, or the database is. Try running a _compact and repair_ on (a copy of) the 2003 database.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I tried this as well and it didn't do anything. The file works perfectly in Access 2007 but objects are missing in 2016

Comment: Then convert it in A2007 to the accdb format, and check if that will work with A2016.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks very much

Comment: Hi Gustav, this worked! thanks very much. I noted that the database had a password so I needed to open it exclusively and remove the password first, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.